# How can I create a inmemory screencapture with php at unix (debian)

Tags: php, debian, screen-capture

The following code, is only available on windows.

```
<?php
  ...
  $im = imagegrabwindow($handle);
  ...      
  imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Whats the solution on unix (debian) php environment, get the screen capture at a php cli programm?

Comment: Could you explain in some more detail what you're trying to achieve? Because a cli php script doesn't require any graphical environment, so the notion of "taking a screen capture" seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: The php cli programm should indentify a target window (with xdotool search --name "Firefox") and analyze window content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds like you want to capture screens from Firefox :p.

For a headless server, make sure Xvfb is installed first, then start it with `Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x24&` (you can change the display *:2* and resolution *1024x768x24* as needed of course).

Run Firefox to open a specific page on that display `DISPLAY=:2 firefox http://www.example.com`. Wait a bit for Firefox to open the page, so execute a `sleep 10` or something similar.

And then throw in some "magic" from ImageMagick (which has to be installed of course) to capture the screen to a file : `import -window root -display :2 example.png`.

And now your processing fun starts :p.

Here's a small bash script putting it all together (Xvfb should already be running though for it to work) :

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":2" /usr/bin/firefox "$1"&
/bin/sleep 10
/usr/bin/import -window root -display :2 "$2"
killall firefox-bin
```

Call that from PHP, and provide it with the URL and filename of the screenshot as parameters.

btw If your server has X you can skip the Xvfb part and use the running X server display (most probably :0).

Comment: Thanks. Thats the HDD solution :) You know a inmemory implementation?